# Where to find practical exercises for algorithm analysis?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

What is a good book or resource to find practical exercises of analysis of the complexity of concrete algorithm implementations (that is, which asymptotic complexity does a particular code have)?

I'm interested not in solving algorithms but in practising finding out their complexity. I have seen a couple of these kind of exercises in my Discrete Mathematics textbook (Rossen), but I haven't been able to find a good resource to find others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textbooks in algorithms are chock full with examples of algorithms, often with analysis. For example, take a look at Erickson's ["Algorithms"](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/), Dasgupta et al ["Algorithms"](http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf). Looking around for lecture notes will get you a lot of others. Analysis of algorithms requires some specialized techniques, a modern overview is Sedgewick and Flajolet's ["Introduction to the analysis of algorithms"](https://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/home/).

Comment: thanks @vonbrand they are good resources. I was looking for something that provided just exercises together with their solutions, but I haven't found something like that. But these kind of books have exercises and some of them are, more or less, what I was looking for. I already know all these techniques but I want to practice them

Comment: I can also recommend ["Generatingfunctionology"](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) by Herbert S. Wilf which has many exercises on generating functions